# How to get the innertext inside a tag?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a VBA to extract a table from a stock website by using XML, but I cannot extract the innertext inside the tag . May I know what's wrong with my code?

I tried to get the innertext by using xxxx.innerText in which xxxx is a MSHTML.IHTMLElement.

```
Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim htmlTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim htmlrow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlcell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Integer
    Dim ColNum As Integer

    Set htmlTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each htmlTable In htmlTables

    If htmlTable.className = "table_list" Then

        RowNum = 2
        For Each htmlrow In htmlTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")

            ColNum = 1
            For Each htmlcell In htmlrow.Children
                Debug.Print htmlcell.innerText
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Next htmlcell

        RowNum = RowNum + 1
        Next htmlrow

    End If
    Next htmlTable

End Sub

Sub GetPrice()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim URL As String

    URL = "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=2&sc_lang=zh-hk"
    XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLPage.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

End Sub
```

I expect the output should be:

即日
52周
最高價
HK$90.700
HK$97.400
...

Answer (score 1):

The page dynamically loads that content which is why an xhr request to initial url is not giving you the expected result.

You can however look in the network tab of the browser and find the endpoint the page is using to update content via seperate xhr.

In the following I am not sure if the token is time based but you can explore that. You need to strip off the outer jquery string but then you can parse the inner json with a json parser. I use [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). You download the jsonconverter.bas code into a standard module called JsonConverter then go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. If you don't want to use a json parser (a parser should be your preference), you could use `split` function to extraxt the info you want.

I would set up the table format in your worksheet with the column and row headers as you want (perhaps as shown on webpage), and the cells formatted as HKD currency - then assign the values from the variables below to the cells within that table. You can tie to a button so you can refresh the table in the sheet at will.

---

**Layout (and result):**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim s As String, json As Object
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www1.hkex.com.hk/hkexwidget/data/getequityquote?sym=2&token=evLtsLsBNAUVTPxtGqVeG6jZbQlrF5FojHmveNua5GgTcjPuBcUs7GTV0hIBAgAI&lang=chi&qid=1560281438643&callback=jQuery311003616462678192556_1560281436567&_=1560281436568", False
        .send
        s = Split(Split(.responseText, "(")(1), ")")(0)
    End With
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("data")("quote")

    Dim sameDayHigh As Double, fiftyTwoWeekHigh As Double, sameDayLow As Double, fiftyTwoWeekLow As Double, timeInfo As String

    sameDayHigh = json("hi")
    sameDayLow = json("lo")
    fiftyTwoWeekHigh = json("hi52")
    fiftyTwoWeekLow = json("lo52")
    timeInfo = json("updatetime")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1) = timeInfo
        .Cells(3, 2).Resize(1, 2) = Array(sameDayHigh, fiftyTwoWeekHigh)
        .Cells(4, 2).Resize(1, 2) = Array(sameDayLow, fiftyTwoWeekLow)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Condensed version of above:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim s As String, json As Object
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www1.hkex.com.hk/hkexwidget/data/getequityquote?sym=2&token=evLtsLsBNAUVTPxtGqVeG6jZbQlrF5FojHmveNua5GgTcjPuBcUs7GTV0hIBAgAI&lang=chi&qid=1560281438643&callback=jQuery311003616462678192556_1560281436567&_=1560281436568", False
        .send
        s = Split(Split(.responseText, "(")(1), ")")(0)
    End With
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("data")("quote")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1) = json("updatetime")
        .Cells(3, 2).Resize(1, 2) = Array(json("hi"), json("hi52"))
        .Cells(4, 2).Resize(1, 2) = Array(json("lo"), json("lo52"))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: May I know how can I get the information if json is not used? Thank you!

Comment: You mean how to get using split function?

Comment: Yes please. How to use the split function?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different than your approach, but it gets the expected result, without looping through the rows:

[image]

Still, later the printed string could be written to a list, thus it is possible to work with it, if it is separated by new line and the empty strings are removed:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With appIE
        .navigate "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=2&sc_lang=zh-hk"
        .Visible = False
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim allData As Object
    Set allData = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("table_list")

    Debug.Print allData.item.outerText
    appIE.Close

End Sub
```